# Multiple metadata values

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata

Just wondering if in a library there is a way to assign multiple values within a single metadata column. I this case I'm building a library of educational documents that need to be tagged for topics. In some cases, however, one document will cover multiple topics such as "Science" and "Math".

Does SharePoint allow you to assign multiple values to a single category?

Answer (score 0):

Go to field settings on the field and check "Allow Multiple Values" and hit Save.

Answer (score 0):

Go library settings> Columns> find the metadata column and click on it. 
[image]

Comment: question is also, how to add by default multiple values, does not seem to be supported